# Android SDK for Google Search?

Tags: android, sdk, google-search-api

### Background

I wish to allow the user to search for images within my app.

I know that Google Search has a deprecated way to search for images ([**here**](https://developers.google.com/image-search)), and now it has a whole new "[**custom search**](https://www.google.com/cse/)" API.

### The problem

No matter where I search, I can't find an SDK that works with the new API, and I also can't find what are the rules of using the API.

### The question

How do you use Google Search within the app ?

Does the API also have a reverse search (for finding out the source of the image), like on TinEye ?

Answer (score 0):

The docs for using the json api are here: https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview

Comment: But isn't there an Android SDK for this ... ?